# Improper Restriction of XML EER for TransformerFactory

Tags: java, xml, veracode

Getting Veracode vulnerability "Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference" for "TransformerFactory", There are several solution for this and the most relevant I found is: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374278/org-xml-sax-saxnotrecognizedexception-property-http-javax-xml-xmlconstants-p). But after trying these solution none of them worked. Below is the code:

```
import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;
.....
 TransformerFactory genericFactory = TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
 genericFactory.setFeature("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD", false);  
 genericFactory.setFeature(Constants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,true);
```

The error is:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Unsupported TransformerFactory feature: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
```

Currently I am running the application on Java 8 and the relevant jars are:
saxon9.jar,
xalan-2.7.2.jar

I tried several combination for these like:

```
//1
 TransformerFactory genericFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 genericFactory.setFeature("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD", false);  
//2
 TransformerFactory genericFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance();
 genericFactory.setFeature("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD", false);
```

But getting the same error. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OWASP when describing how to prevent [XML eXternal Entity injection (XXE)](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), when using Java and `TransformerFactory` the [recommended approach](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#transformerfactory) is the following:

```java
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

Please, note they are configuring attributes, not features.

Please, consider review as well the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) provided for the `setAttribute` method in `TransformerFactory`, I think it can be of help:

> Access to external DTDs in the source file is restricted to the
> protocols specified by the `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD`
> property. If access is denied during transformation due to the
> restriction of this property, `TransformerException` will be thrown
> by `Transformer.transform(Source, Result)`.
>
> Access to external DTDs in the stylesheet is restricted to the
> protocols specified by the `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD`
> property. If access is denied during the creation of a new
> transformer due to the restriction of this property,
> `TransformerConfigurationException` will be thrown by the
> `newTransformer(Source)` method.
>
> Access to external reference set by the stylesheet processing
> instruction, Import and Include element is restricted to the
> protocols specified by the `XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET`
> property. If access is denied during the creation of a new transformer
> due to the restriction of this property,
> `TransformerConfigurationException` will be thrown by the
> `newTransformer(Source)` method.

Comment: Although, this didn't worked for me as under XMLConstants class, there is no "XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD" property. Still searching for the soluton.