# org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized

Tags: java, xml, maven

colleagues! I have the issue above and already saw the article(-s) [org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374278/org-xml-sax-saxnotrecognizedexception-property-http-javax-xml-xmlconstants-p) with some ways of solution this problem  but it doesn't help me.

I use maven and from main pom I have:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need it, because if I delete it than I have 'javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found'. The main goal is to add three property like ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD from javax.xml.XMLConstants but anyway I tried it wasn't successful.

I tried to:

1. Use System.property;
2. Use ClassLoader;

   final SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl", ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

I had ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
```

3. Use default instance:

   final SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newDefaultInstance();
   But 'newDefaultInstance()' method wasn't recognized too.
4. Delete xerces dependency from main pom and use

   System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory",
   "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");

to found DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl but it also wasn't success.

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: Used jdk is: jdk-11.0.10

Comment: I think you should be using `newDefaultInstance()` available since JDK 9; I can't think why that wouldn't be working if you really are using jdk 11.

Comment: Yeah, I've used it, but had issue where was said that 'newDefaultInstance() method is not found/not recognized' although I see this method from javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory